# Why can't vb catch a query error

Tags: .net, vb.net, ms-access

This is my current code:

```
Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM tblPiglets WHERE Week=@week AND SowOrder=@so AND PigletNumber=@pig"

    Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(query, con)
        With cmd.Parameters
            .AddWithValue("@week", txtWeek.Text)
            .AddWithValue("@so", txtSo.Text)
            .AddWithValue("@pig", txtPiglet.Text)
        End With
        Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        While dr.Read
            Dim loc As String
            loc = dr("CurrentLocation").ToString()
            If loc = ComboBox1.Text Then
                confirmed()
            Else
                invalid()
            End If
        End While
    End Using
```

First user is oblige to input a unique id, which is week, sow order and number. Then it will check if the selected item's `CurrentLocation` field is the same to `ComboBox1.Text`. If yes, go on, if not, error.
However, **Nothing** happens when the user inserted a *not existing* data. Say, I have 3 data (*unique "id's"*).

1. 1-1-0
2. 1-1-1
3. 2-1-0

If I try to input 2-1-1, *which is not existent*, nothing happens. I would like to catch this, so the user will know that its an invalid input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check whether there are any results yourself. For an SQL query, it is not an error if it does not return any rows.
The following code is an example for such a check:

```
Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
If dr.Read() Then
    Do 
       Dim loc As String
       loc = dr("CurrentLocation").ToString()
       If loc = ComboBox1.Text Then
           confirmed()
       Else
            invalid()
        End If
   Loop While dr.Read()
Else
    ' Add code for no records here
End If
```

Note that if you want to check for an invalid id specifically, you'd need to add a special check for that. The above sample only checks whether any rows were returned. The reason for this could also be that there are no data for week or soworder.

Comment: this is just fine, I just wanted to catch if there are no data existing based on the user input. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add some code that checks that the dr is not null.

```
If Not IsNothing(dr) Then
   While dr.read.... 

Else
  'No records
End If
```